# How to enable passphrase callback (instead of prompt) in `pygpgme`?

Tags: python, bash, gnupg, gpgme

I am writing software to retrieve encrypted files, decrypt them and populate a data lake on AWS S3 with the information contained in them on a scheduled basis. The files are encrypted with a GPG key and we are using the `pygpgme` (https://launchpad.net/pygpgme) package for cryptography. I am on a Mac, I have GPG 2.2.16 and `pygpgme` 0.3 installed.

The private key we use to decrypt the files has a passphrase.

I've tried multiple techniques/suggestions I've found online, including:

- http://www.topdog.za.net/2012/05/23/python-modules-you-should-know:-pygpgme/
- trying to change the `Context().pinentry_mode` parameter, which seems to *not* exist in my version of `pygpgme`
- trying to add parameters to `{GNUPGHOME}/gpg.conf`:

  - batch
  - use-agent

None disable the prompt.

Here is the code I use for assigning the passphrase callback:

```py
ctx.passphrase_cb = \
        lambda uid_hint, passphrase_info, prev_was_bad, fd: os.write(
            fd, b'{}\\n'.format(EQF_PASSPHRASE)
        )
```

Here is my `gpg.conf`:

```
# don't prompt for a password!
batch

# Try to use the GnuPG-Agent. With this option, GnuPG first tries to connect to
# the agent before it asks for a passphrase.
use-agent
```

Nonetheless, I get a prompt asking for a passphrase in the command line every time I run the service. How can I make the software use the callback I provide?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of tinkering around, I've made it work using the following configuration at `{GNUPGHOME}/gpg.conf`:

```
batch
pinentry-mode loopback
```

I can the use `passphrase_cb` in the Python code as intended.

Hope this helps!